# Import a JSON project wise, so it loads just once

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, jsonschema

I have a Python project that performs a JSON validation against a specific schema.
It will run as a Transform step in GCP Dataflow, so it's very important that all dependencies are gathered before the run to avoid downloading the same file again and again.

The schema is placed in a separated Git repository.
The nature of the Transformer is that you receive a single record in your class, and you work with it. The typical flow is that you load the JSON Schema, you validate the record against it, and then you do stuff with the invalid and with the valid. Loading the schema in this way means that I download the schema from the repo for every record, and it could be hundred thousands.
The code gets "cloned" into the workers and then work kinda independent.

Inspired by the way Python loads the requirements at the beginning (one single time) and using them as imports, I thought I could add the repository (where the JSON schema lives) as a Python requirement, and then simply use it in my Python code. But of course, it's a JSON, not a Python module to be imported. How can it work?

An example would be something like:

- requirements.txt

```
git+git://github.com/path/to/json/schema@41b95ec
```

- dataflow_transformer.py

```
import apache_beam as beam
import the_downloaded_schema
from jsonschema import validate

class Verifier(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, record: dict):
        validate(instance=record, schema=the_downloaded_schema)

        # ... more stuff

        yield record

class Transformer(beam.PTransform):
    def expand(self, record):
        return (
            record
            | "Verify Schema" >> beam.ParDo(Verifier())
        )
```

Comment: Have you thought of using side inputs? you could pass your JSON schema as a side input and validate your records in the main input, using it. [Here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs) is the documentation for it. Did it help you?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes I'll take a look, sounds interesting, thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the json schema once and use it as a side input.
An example:

```
import json
import requests

json_current='https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/current.json'

def get_json_schema(url):
  with requests.Session() as session:
    schema = json.loads(session.get(url).text)
  return schema

schema_json = get_json_schema(json_current)

def feed_schema(data, schema):
  yield {'record': data, 'schema': schema[0]}

schema = p | beam.Create([schema_json])
data = p | beam.Create(range(10))
data_with_schema = data | beam.FlatMap(feed_schema, schema=beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(schema))
# Now do your schema validation
```

Just a demonstration of what the `data_with_schema` pcollection looks like
[image]

Comment: I ended up implementing side inputs, taking this as an inspiration. Worked as expected. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a class for loading your resources that uses a cache in order to prevent double loading? Something along the lines of:

```
class JsonLoader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = set()

    def import(self, filename):
        filename = os.path.absname(filename)
        if filename not in self.cache:
            self._load_json(filename)
            self.cache.add(filename)

    def _load_json(self, filename):
        ...
```

Comment: This way it would download the schema once per worker. And would get destroyed at the end of the process, so any update on the schema would be loaded in every new run of the pipeline. It's cool, thanx :-)

Comment: I don't quite get it: you say you want to use sth. similar to Python's `import` mechanism which suggests you're running a single python process. But  then you might as well just use a singleton instance of a class like the one above?!

Comment: What I want to achieve is to avoid downloading the schema from git from every single record. My first impression is to use something similar to Python's `import` if possible. A singleton caching the call would reduce the download drastically, which then I don't discard, but still intending to go for my first approach idea.